# Paypal sandbox returning 500 error

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm using Paypal Sandbox to test my site. Few days ago it was ok and coming to the final stages of testing and all of a sudden i get a 500 error returned. The issue started yesterday so thought it would be resolved by today but i dont know if something has changed which I'm not aware of or how i could check the status and when the service would resume?

I get the following returned

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Sat, 24 Jun 2017 08:37:50 GMT
Server: Apache
Paypal-Debug-Id: d48964f5c065
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=14400
X-Cnection: close
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 1
```

Can anyone advise how to go from here? I tried checking for a status page but non that i saw mentioned any maintenance work. If i've changed something i would have assumed a different error status but considering its 500 it leads me to believe its something to do with PP Sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

as pperejon says, it is an issue at PayPal's end, if you take some of PayPal's sample code and copy it into a file called 'index.html':

```
 <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="PayPalMerchant@example.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Widget">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="submit" value="Buy Now">
 </form>
```

Then open it in your web-browser and click the "Buy Now" button, it will connect to PayPal as normal; however, change [paypal](http://www.paypal.com) to [paypal sandbox](http://sandbox.paypal.com) and instead you will get the following warning:

> "This site is not secure"
>
> "This might mean that someone’s trying to fool you or steal any info
>   you send to the server. You should close this site immediately."

Clicking the "More information" button just below the error gives a little more detail:

> "Error Code: DLG_FLAGS_SEC_CERT_CN_INVALID"

If you ignore the SSL certificate warning and still attempt to open the sandbox page you will then encounter the Server 500 error.

I do not know if there are two issues here (the Certificate and 500 error) or if one is causing the other, but either way it is PayPal to fix. It's Monday, so I am hoping that sometime in the next 48 hours it will get fixed as there will be plenty of people being affected by it.

Comment: Its been like this since last Thursday which is about 5 days now. Ridiculous this has not been resolved within a timely manner. Thanks for your help